# DNS Server- subdomains on internal LAN and www on public IP

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, dns-zone

I have a Windows 2008R2 based domain controller also working as internal DNS server for my domain say "domain1.com".

I also have a working website www.domain2.com hosted elsewhere and accessible globally.

Now I am creating a test environment on my internal network where I am going to add a couple of subdomains, say sub1.domain2.com and sub2.domain2.com
These subdomains/webpages are hosted internally (LAN).

I have created a new zone on my DNS server and added A records so that I can have both these sundomains mapped to respective internal IP addresses.

These subdomain DNS requests are working as expected.
But now the problem is that my live website www.domain2.com is inaccessible from
my internal network. My windows DNS server is unable to handle requests for it, though I have added an A record on my internal DNS server pointing to the public IP of website. Have I missed something here?

Regards,

Vin

Answer (score 0):

When you create the zone, create the subdomain and not the root domain.

So create 2 zones, sub1.domain2.com.

Delete domain2.com zone so your server stops answering nxdomain for www.domain2.com

I use this method to split-dns my premise exchange servers.

Answer (score -1):

Cause i have not 50 Reputation i'm not able to add an normal Comment. So had to do a normal comment, really strange the permission system here.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2015/05/12/split-brain-dns-deployment-using-windows-dns-server-policies.aspx

Split Brain DNS, should be a good hint.